# Jmeter websocket: restart thread in case of error

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I'm using WebSocket Jmeter plugin. In my flow I need to close the websocket, which I'm doing by adding 1 minute sleep, which causes socket close, but also an error:
ERROR - JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket: Disconnect 1006: WebSocket Read EOF. I'm continuing the flow but after a few hours jmeter gets out of memory and "dies". Looks like this is because for each socket close, additional jmeter thread is opened, which causes memory leak.

1. What is the right way to close websocket?
2. If my solution is to stop the thread on error, how can I immediately start a new thread?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Couldn't you use `Close Connection Pattern` to specify the last response, after which connection should be closed?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Jmeter Websocket, I get empty response for close connection.
So there is no close pattern, in this case I make Response patter - Message backlog 0 and Timeout response 0. 
This way Websocket connection is closed.

If you are running in loop, you check Reset Streaming connection. In this way all connections are closed and new connection is opened for every  new loop.